# Почему иконка из FontAwesome не работает?

Tags: html, fontawesome

Помогите плиз. Первая иконка из FontAwesome работает, а вторая - никак нет. Почему?

```
<head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" 
          href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" 
          integrity="sha384- 
          fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" 
          crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
     <span class="clock-span"><i class="far fa-clock"></i> 15mins</span>
     <span class="easy-span"><i class="fad fa-signal-alt-3"></i> Easy</span>
</body>
```

Comment: Потому что она платная. Если ты конечно не покупал лицензию.

Comment: не, платные же во втором ряду, да и написали бы же, что платная...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема явно в том, что в подключаемом вами CSS (https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css) нет нужного класса (.fa-signal-alt-3).

Может иконка платная, а может вы указали неправильный класс, но в файле её нет)